# MonadPlus and forever - what is the relation?

Tags: haskell

I see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#forever)

```
-- Note that "forever" isn't necessarily non-terminating.
-- If the action is in a @'MonadPlus'@ and short-circuits after some number of iterations.
-- then @'forever'@ actually returns `mzero`, effectively short-circuiting its caller.
```

To be honest I don't understand this note. Do they mean that it is possible to break `forever` with `MonadPlus`, for instance - `IO Bool`? Let's say, `IO False` will break it...

From one point of view `IO` is `MonadPlus` too. Maybe I must wrap my `IO Bool` in something else to achieve the possibility to break `forever` with `IO Bool` and `MonadPlus`? What does the note mean at all?

Sure, I can break it with exception or to implement own `forever` but my interest is about this strange note.

Comment: For example, `forever (mzero :: Maybe Int)` just returns `Nothing`. For `IO`, `forever (mzero :: IO ())` throws an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can look at how `forever` is implemented:

```
forever :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f b
forever a = let a' = a *> a' in a'
```

The documentation of [`(*>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--62-) says that it *"sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument"*. It basically is a `(>>)` for Applicatives instead of Monads.

So if you look at how `forever` is implemented you'll see that it basically is expanded to:

```
forever a = a *> a *> a *> ...
```

As the `forever` description says, if the Applicative has some short-circuiting behaviour it can still terminate and not evaluate the infinite sequence of actions:

```
ghci> forever $ Nothing
Nothing
ghci> forever $ Just 1
-- infinite loop trying to evaluate Just 1 *> Just 1 *> Just 1 *> ...
```

That is because `(Nothing *> _) = Nothing` what follows the `(*>)` is not even evaluated, so `Nothing *> Nothing *> Nothing *> ...` short-circuits to `Nothing` without having to evaluate the infinite list of actions.

Comment: “[`(*>)`] basically is a `(>>)` for Applicatives instead of Monads.” – it is **literally** a `(>>)` that doesn't require a `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 11):

One may naively assume that `forever m` just goes on forever:

```
forever m = m >> forever m
          = m >> m >> forever m
          = m >> m >> m >> ...  -- forever
```

But the comment mentions that there are ways to break the loop, and `mzero` is a concise example, that demonstrates the situation equationally rather than by thinking about exceptions operationally. `mzero` satisfies `mzero >> w = mzero` for all `w`, so that:

```
forever mzero = mzero >> forever mzero
              = mzero
```

The point is that the choice of monad makes `forever` much more versatile than a mere `while (true)` loop in imperative languages.